# Can I put content inside a row in bootstrap 3's grid?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, row

I'm building a layout where many rows will span the entire containing column. I'm wondering if I should nest a `col-12` inside each of these rows and put content in there or if I should just put the  content inside the row?

So, is this OK:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="my-lazy-content"></div>
</div>
```

Or, is it better to put a column in there too:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="my-verbose-content></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the content to span the entire column, you should add in the `col-xs-12` wrapping div around your content. This ensures that the content has that 15px of padding to the left and right and doesn't simply "hard-align" to the edges of the `row` element since the row class has negative `-15px` of margin to compensate for the container's `15px` padding?

Is it absolutely necessary to have the `row`s? If the content simply spans the entire width of the container, why not just nest your content directly within the container as follows:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I didn't realize the `15px` padding detail. I think I'll go with the verbose columns inside rows just to keep everything consistent and simple. fingers crossed that this makes it easier to maintain.